# HTML - Navigation menu over header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building currently my web-page on Github ([Githug Page](https://edualvarado.github.io/)), and I am having some troubles with the top-nav menu. As you can see, when you scroll down, the menu disappears, and when you scroll up, it appears again. Nevertheless, I would like to make the behaviour much more simpler, and that is, to make it fixed with respect the header. In other words, I just want the menu to appear on top of the page, like another element more. I do not want the menu to follow the scrolling. Looks simple but I do not end up getting the result.

This is my current `main.js`.

```js
(function($) {

 var $window = $(window),
  $body = $('body');

 // Breakpoints.
  breakpoints({
   xlarge:   [ '1141px',  '1680px' ],
   large:    [ '981px',   '1140px' ],
   medium:   [ '737px',   '980px'  ],
   small:    [ '481px',   '736px'  ],
   xsmall:   [ '321px',   '480px'  ],
   xxsmall:  [ null,      '320px'  ]
  });

 // Play initial animations on page load.
  $window.on('load', function() {
   window.setTimeout(function() {
    $body.removeClass('is-preload');
   }, 100);
  });

 // Scrolly.
  $('.scrolly').scrolly();

})(jQuery);

/* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("header_nav").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header_nav").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

The `index.html` file, where you can see, the important sections are `header` and `header_nav`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
 Photon by HTML5 UP
 html5up.net | @ajlkn
 Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Eduardo Alvarado</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
  <!-- Load an icon library to show a hamburger menu (bars) on small screens -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 </head>
 <body class="is-preload">
  
  <!-- Header Menu -->
   <section id="header_nav"> 
    <nav id="nav">
     <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
       <li><a href="index" class="button small"><p style="color:white">Home</p></a></li>
       <li><a href="" class="button small"><p style="color:white">Research</p></a></li>
       <li><a href="" class="button small"><p style="color:white">Game-dev</p></a></li>
       <li><a href="photography" class="button small"><p style="color:white">Photography</p></a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </nav>
   </section>
  
  <!-- Header -->
   <section id="header"> 
    <div class="inner">   
     <span><img src="/images/car_final_256_header.gif"></span>
     <h1>Hi, I'm <strong>Eduardo Alvarado</strong>.</h1>
     <h1>A passionate software engineer who develops intelligent<br />
     cars during the day and loves to design<br />
     game-focus art and applications in his spare-time.</h1>
     <br />
     <p>Want to contact me? Send me a message at <a href="mailto:alvaradopinero.eduardo@gmail.com">alvaradopinero.eduardo@gmail.com</a>.</p>
     <ul class="actions special">
      <li><a href="#one" class="button scrolly">Discover</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </section>

  <!-- One -->
   <section id="one" class="main style1">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row gtr-150">
      <div class="col-6 col-12-medium imp-medium">
       <header class="major">
        <h2>Background</h2>
       </header>
       <p align="justify">I am a first year PhD Researcher at <a href='https://www.daimler.com/career/about-us/insights/research-development/'>Daimler AG</a> in Stuttgart, Germany. My research is centered on robust perception for human activity recognition. Prior joininig Daimler, I graduated with a master's degree in <b>Embedded Systems Engineering</b>, with a major in Artificial Intelligence and Autonomous Intelligent Systems from <a href='https://www.uni-freiburg.de/'>Albert-Ludwigs-Universität Freiburg</a>, and with a bachelor's degree in <b>Electronics and Automation Engineering</b> from <a href='https://www.uc3m.es/home'>Universidad Carlos III</a> in Madrid.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-12-medium">
       <span class="image fit"><img src="images/profile_bg_1920_1080.png" alt="" style="padding-top: 12px" /></span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>

  <!-- Two -->
   <section id="two" class="main style2">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row gtr-150">
      <div class="col-6 col-12-medium">
       <ul class="major-icons">
        <li><span class="icon solid style4 major fa-laptop-code"></span></li>
        <li><span class="icon solid style2 major fa-microchip"></span></li>
        <li><span class="icon solid style3 major fa-brain"></span></li>
        <li><span class="icon solid style5 major fa-gamepad"></span></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-12-medium">
       <p align="justify">I have dedicated my academic career to the field of robotics, with special interest in AI-based Perception and Behavior Planning applied to intelligent-mobility. I wrote my master's thesis at <a href='https://www.bosch.com/research/'>Robert Bosch GmbH</a> on DL sensor-fusion architectures for Object Detection and Tracking, under the supervision from <a href='https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=2mv2dDkAAAAJ&hl=en'>Prof. Dr. Joschka Boedecker</a> and <a href='https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=LcARjz0AAAAJ&hl=en'>Prof. Dr. Abnihav Valada</a>. I also worked as development-intern at <a href='https://www.zf.com/mobile/en/homepage/homepage.html'>ZF Friedrichshafen</a> on the design of ROS SW-tools for self-driving vehicles. Additionally, I have been working as research assistant for Autonomous Intelligent Systems at the university, on the development of SLAM algorithms and Autonomous Driving simulations.</p>
       <p align="justify">I dedicate my day to day to my other great passion too, game-related development and 2D/3D design. Since I was a child, I have always loved bringing to reality dream worlds, characters and landscapes only possible in one's imagination. Little by little, I try to learn more about design, gameplay and visual programming.</p>      </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>

  <!-- Three -->
   <section id="three" class="main style1 special">
    <div class="container">
     <header class="major">
      <h2>My work</h2>
     </header>
     <div class="row gtr-150">
      <div class="col-4 col-12-medium">
       <span class="image fit"><img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" /></span>
       <h3>Research and Academic Service</h3>
       <p>Publications, preprints, SW/HW proyects and news.</p>
       <ul class="actions special">
        <li><a href="#" class="button">More</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-12-medium">
       <span class="image fit"><img src="images/pic03.jpg" alt="" /></span>
       <h3>Game Development</h3>
       <p>Game applications, 2D/3D design and visual programming.</p>
       <ul class="actions special">
        <li><a href="#" class="button">More</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 col-12-medium">
       <span class="image fit"><img src="images/pic04.jpg" alt="" /></span>
       <h3>Photography</h3>
       <p>A small portfolio of my favorite trips and places.</p>
       <ul class="actions special">
        <li><a href="/photography" class="button">More</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>

  <!-- Four -->
   <!--
   <section id="four" class="main style2 special">
    <div class="container">
     <header class="major">
      <h2>Ipsum feugiat consequat?</h2>
     </header>
     <p>Sed lacus nascetur ac ante amet sapien.</p>
     <ul class="actions special">
      <li><a href="#" class="button wide primary">Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="button wide">Learn More</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </section>
   -->
  
  <!-- Footer -->
   <section id="footer">
    <ul class="icons">
     <li><a href="docs/CV.pdf" class="icon solid alt fa-id-card"><span class="label">CV</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="mailto:alvaradopinero.eduardo@gmail.com" class="icon solid alt fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="https://github.com/edualvarado" class="icon brands alt fa-github"><span class="label">GitHub</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="icon brands alt fa-google"><span class="label">Google Scholar</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="copyright">
     <li>&copy; Untitled</li><li>Design: <a href="http://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a></li>
    </ul>
   </section>

  <!-- Scripts -->
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

And finally, the respective part of the `css`.

```css
/* Header */

 #header {
  padding: 9em 0 9em 0 ;
  background-color: #4686a0;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  background-attachment: fixed,       fixed,       fixed;
  background-image: url("images/overlay2.png"), url("images/overlay3.svg"), linear-gradient(45deg, #9dc66b 5%, #4fa49a 30%, #4361c2);
  background-position: top left,      center center,     center center;
  background-size: auto,       cover,       cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
 }

  #header a {
   border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }

   #header a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
   }

  #header h1, #header h2, #header h3, #header h4, #header h5, #header h6, #header strong, #header b {
   color: #ffffff;
  }

  #header header p {
   color: #ffffff;
  }

  #header header.major:after {
   background: #ffffff;
  }

  #header input[type="submit"],
  #header input[type="reset"],
  #header input[type="button"],
  #header button,
  #header .button {
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff;
   color: #ffffff !important;
  }

   #header input[type="submit"]:hover,
   #header input[type="reset"]:hover,
   #header input[type="button"]:hover,
   #header button:hover,
   #header .button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125);
   }

   #header input[type="submit"]:active,
   #header input[type="reset"]:active,
   #header input[type="button"]:active,
   #header button:active,
   #header .button:active {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
   }

   #header input[type="submit"].primary,
   #header input[type="reset"].primary,
   #header input[type="button"].primary,
   #header button.primary,
   #header .button.primary {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ffffff !important;
    color: #4686a0 !important;
   }

    #header input[type="submit"].primary:hover,
    #header input[type="reset"].primary:hover,
    #header input[type="button"].primary:hover,
    #header button.primary:hover,
    #header .button.primary:hover {
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.125) !important;
     color: #ffffff !important;
    }

    #header input[type="submit"].primary:active,
    #header input[type="reset"].primary:active,
    #header input[type="button"].primary:active,
    #header button.primary:active,
    #header .button.primary:active {
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) !important;
    }

  #header ul.major-icons li .icon {
   border-color: #ffffff;
  }

  #header .icon.major {
   color: #ffffff;
  }

  #header h1 {
   margin: 0;
  }

  #header p {
   margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  }

  #header .actions {
   -moz-justify-content: center;
   -webkit-justify-content: center;
   -ms-justify-content: center;
   justify-content: center;
   margin-top: 2.5em;
   margin-left: 0;
   position: relative;
  }

   #header .actions li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
   }

   #header .actions:after {
    background: #ffffff;
    content: '';
    height: 100vh;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: 1px;
   }

  #header .inner {
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1.5s ease, opacity 2s ease;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.5s ease, opacity 2s ease;
   -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1.5s ease, opacity 2s ease;
   transition: transform 1.5s ease, opacity 2s ease;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0.25s;
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0.25s;
   transition-delay: 0.25s;
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -ms-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
   opacity: 1;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
  }

   #header .inner .actions {
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1.25s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1.25s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1.25s ease;
    transition: transform 1.25s ease;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 1s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
   }

  #header:after {
   -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease;
   -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
   -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease;
   transition: opacity 1s ease;
   background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #4fa49a, #4361c2);
   content: '';
   height: 100%;
   left: 0;
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
  }

 body.is-preload #header .inner {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  opacity: 0;
 }

  body.is-preload #header .inner .actions {
   -moz-transform: translateY(30em);
   -webkit-transform: translateY(30em);
   -ms-transform: translateY(30em);
   transform: translateY(30em);
   opacity: 0;
  }

 body.is-preload #header:after {
  opacity: 1;
 }

/* Header_nav */

 #page-wrapper {
  padding-top: 3.5em;
 }

 #header_nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.25em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  cursor: default;
  height: 3.5em;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 3.5em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
 }

  #header_nav h1 {
   height: inherit;
   left: 1.25em;
   line-height: inherit;
   margin: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
  }

  #header_nav nav {
   position: absolute;
   right: 1em;
   top: 0;
  }

   #header_nav nav ul {
    margin: 0;
   }

    #header_nav nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 1em;
    }

     #header_nav nav ul li a, #header_nav nav ul li span {
      border: 0;
      color: inherit;
      display: inline-block;
      height: inherit;
      line-height: inherit;
      outline: 0;
     }

      #header_nav nav ul li a.button, #header_nav nav ul li span.button {
       height: 2em;
       line-height: 2em;
       padding: 0 1.25em;
      }

      #header_nav nav ul li a:not(.button):before, #header_nav nav ul li span:not(.button):before {
       margin-right: 0.5em;
      }

     #header_nav nav ul li.active > a, #header_nav nav ul li.active > span {
      color: #e44c65;
     }

     #header_nav nav ul li > ul {
      display: none;
     }

 body.landing #page-wrapper {
  padding-top: 0;
 }

 body.landing #header_nav {
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  position: absolute;
 }
```

To summarize, I would like the menu to be only on the top of the page, over the header, nothing more. I would really appreciate your help. I have tried several things but I still not very experimented in web-design, I am sorry.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the styling for `#header_nav`, set `position` to `absolute` instead of `fixed`. Then remove the following from `main.js`:

```js
/* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
  var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("header_nav").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header_nav").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

This way, the menu will render over the header but not stay at the top of the page when the user scrolls down.

Edit: If you want the menu to render above the header, not on top of it, remove the `position` line completely.